# Paranoia with belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-paranoia

In my application a user `has_many :jobs` and a job `belongs_to :user`. I'm using the paranoia gem to soft delete users and jobs.

Lets say I have a user, Joe, and he has a job "Push changes". I can see all the jobs on my listing page by using `Job.all`, but as soon as I delete Joes' account I can't see the job using `Job.all` anymore.

I have tried to use `Job.with_deleted.all` and also tried to unscope the association `belongs_to :user, -> { with_deleted }`.

The SQL statement produced:

```
SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "jobs"."user_id" AND "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL WHERE "jobs"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY users.name ASC
```

Comment: what are you using to delete? object.delete or or object.destroy? You should be using destroy

Comment: I am, I can still the user by using `User.with_deleted`. It's frustrating that `"users"."deleted_at" IS NULL` is added to my query, that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you have set `dependent: :destroy` on the has many jobs, that's the only way where deleting a user, will make changes on the has_many. of you don't want them to be hided to, then just remove the dependent: :destroy from the user model on the has many jobs

Answer (score 0):

Paranoia gem sets a default scope to your model where deleted_at attr set with timestamps are not returned.
Try unscoping your model like

`User.unscoped.all`

Answer (score 0):

I know maybe it's too late to answer this question, but from my experience. Adding `include Mongoid::Paranoia` to the Job model will add `deleted_at` to associations instead of really deleting job records. Also, if you want to query the **deleted** jobs, try using `Job.unscoped.all`, or if want to get the deleted `User` from job instance, try adding a method

```
def user
  User.find(user_id)
end
```

Replace the `user_id` with your actual key name which maps to User id.

Hope it helps! :)